# PHP retrieve xml node value with simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP SimpleXML get innerXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937056/php-simplexml-get-innerxml)

I've seen others questions related to simplexml and node value but couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I have a PHP var which contains an xml document formed like that :

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main">
      ##CONTENTS## cd <strong>dscsdcsd</strong> sdcsc
  <div>my content here</div>
  <span>and there</span>
    </div>
<div id="footer"> </div>
</div>
```

I want to retrieve the  node **value**. But with the following code, I also retrieve the  tag :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($_POST['newsletter_body']);
$att = 'id';

  foreach ($xml->children() as $el) {
    if($el->attributes()->$att == 'main') {
      $body_content = $el->asXml();
    }
  }
```

Could someone tell me how to get only **node value** (without using xpath)?

To be clear, now I get :

```
<div id="main">
      ##CONTENTS## cd <strong>dscsdcsd</strong> sdcsc
      <div>my content here</div>
      <span>and there</span>
</div>
```

And I just want :

```
      ##CONTENTS## cd <strong>dscsdcsd</strong> sdcsc
      <div>my content here</div>
      <span>and there</span>
```

Many thanks

Comment: "node Value" is an ambiguous term. You are asking for innerXML whereas nodeValue usually referes to inner text without XML tags.

Comment: @Tomalak > in fact, it is. Sorry for that!

Comment: @lenzai > Yes, but, I don't understand why simplexml as no method to get innerXml with xml value inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Tomalak, this is a duplicate of [Stackoverflow: PHP SimpleXML get innerXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937056/php-simplexml-get-innerxml)
and you cannot do better than suggested with simplexml API.

```
function simplexml_innerXML($xml)
{
    $content="";
    foreach($node->children() as $child)
        $content .= $child->asXml();
    return $content;
}
```

In your code, replace `$body_content = $el->asXml();` with `$body_content = simplexml_innerXML($el);`

---

However, you could also switch to another API that ofers distinction between `innerXML`(what you are looking for) and `outerXML` (what you get for now). Microsoft Dom libary offers this distinction but unfortunately PHP DOM doesn't.

I found that `PHP XMLReader API` offers this distintion. See [readInnerXML()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.readinnerxml.php). Though this API has quite a different approach to processing XML. Try it.

---

Finally, I would stress that XML is not meant to extract data as subtrees but rather as value. That's why you running into trouble finding the right API. It would be more 'standard' to store HTML subtree as a value (and escape all tags) rather than XML subtree. Also beware that some HTML synthax are not always XML compatible ( i.e. `<br> vs ,<br/>` ). Anyway in practice, you approach is definitely more convenient for editing the xml file.

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try to that but I will probably use simplexml ° the SimpleDOM external library mentioned in the other thread. readInnerXML() uses php 5.2 since simplexml uses only PHP 5. I need the app to be generic

Comment: I was suggesting their second option with custom iteration. see my update above.

Comment: I posted the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937056/php-simplexml-get-innerxml/6327025 also