# Parsing XML file

Tags: php, xml

I've got a problem with parsing an XML file (nb. well formed one).

Consider XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
    <list>
        <item no="1">
            <title>Item's 1 title</title>
            <content>Some long content with <special>tags</special> inside</content>
        </item>
        <item no="2">
            <title>Item's 2 title</title>
            <content>Some long content with <special>tags</special> inside</content>
        </item>
    </list>
</root>
```

I need to get contents  contents of each item in the list and put them in an array. Generally not a problem, but in this case, I can't get my head round it.

Problem lays in `<content>` contents. It is string with tags in-between. I can't find a way to extract the contents. SimpleXML returns/echoes just the string with anything including and inside `<special>` tags stripped out. Like this:

```
Some long content with inside.
```

I'd ideally want it to get a string like this:

```
Some long content with <special>tags</special> inside
```

How do I get it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SimpleXML get innerXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937056/php-simplexml-get-innerxml)

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to mix text nodes with other nodes. Ideally your XML should be like `<content><![CDATA[Some long content with <special>tags</special> inside]]></content>` which instructs parser not to parse content within CDATA tag (return it as is)

Comment: @mkilmanas Well, that's what an application's API returns, so I have no choice there.

Comment: @Gordon You might be right. Thanks for the link, will investigate.

Comment: well, the accepted solution suggests to use a 3rd partly library. Personally, I'm not too fond of those non-native solutions, but that's just me. Anyways, if you want to investigate some more you now know the term: innerXML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) which is built into PHP.

```
<?php

$xml = <<<END
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
    <list>
        <item no="1">
            <title>Item's 1 title</title>
            <content>Some long content with <special>tags</special> inside</content>
        </item>
        <item no="2">
            <title>Item's 2 title</title>
            <content>Some long content with <special>tags</special> inside</content>
        </item>
    </list>
</root>
END;

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('content');

foreach ( $nodes as $node )
{
  $temp_doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    
  foreach ( $node->childNodes as $child )
    $temp_doc->appendChild($temp_doc->importNode($child, true));
    
  echo $temp_doc->saveHTML(); // Outputs: Some long content with <special>tags</special> inside
}
```

To select the top level "content" elements (in case there are "content" elements inside), you can use [`DOMXPath`](https://www.php.net/domxpath).

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadXML($xml); // $xml from the example above

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$nodes = $xpath->query('/root/list/item/content');

foreach ( $nodes as $node )
{
  $temp_doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    
  foreach ( $node->childNodes as $child )
    $temp_doc->appendChild($temp_doc->importNode($child, true));
    
  echo $temp_doc->saveHTML(); // Outputs: Some long content with <special>tags</special> inside
}
```

Comment: nice,what if the text node contain tag 'content'?

Comment: @ajreal - You could use DOMXPath to fetch only the top level "content" tag. I'll update my example.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML just doesn't support mixed content (text nodes with element nodes as siblings). I suggest you use [XMLReader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SimpleXML's asXML function.  It will return that called node as the xml string;

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
foreach($xml->list->item as $item) {
    $content = $item->contents->asXML();
    echo $content."\n";
}
```

will print:

```
<content>Some long content with <special>tags</special> inside</content>
<content>Some long content with <special>tags</special> inside</content>
```

it's a little ugly but you could then clip out the `<content>` and `</content>` with a substr:

```
$content = substr($content,9,-10);
```