# php simplexml asXML returns incl. outer element

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i managed to load a table (4x4 fields, links in first row) to simplexml, where on a link I expect returning only inner html of the link (bolds etc) but it returns whole element

```
  foreach($xml->tbody->children() as $tr){
  $row++;
  for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++)   {  
     $data[$row][$i]= $tr->td[$i]->asXML();   
     if($row==1)
     { $href[$i] = (string)$tr->td[$i]->a[0]['href'];
       $titl[$i] = $tr->td[$i]->a[0]->asXML(); // PROBLEMATIC POINT
     }
  }  

expected: 'link<b>text</b>'
returned: '<a href="....">link<b>text</b></a>'  /e.g. whole 'a' element/
```

if I would add the (string) type setting, I would loose the inner formating of the link,

 while the above **`$tr->td[$i]`** returns only inner content of element td

Comment: just noticed trying to use (string) typesetting returns only unwrapped a text so any bold would be omitted ... bypassable by strip_tags to getplain text of link

Comment: SimpleXML has nothing to return inner XML of an element out of the box. So what is your question?

Comment: then why if I do `$tr->td[$i]` it returns for example `hello` /inner content of that element/ instead of `<td>hello</td>` ??

Comment: i'd like to achieve using only built-in php classes so no external classes solutions, if possible

Comment: I think this is one of those occasions where I'd go with the DOM over SimpleXML, as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7128991/157957 The reason being you need to iterate over both the text nodes and child elements, which SimpleXML simplifies out of your reach...

Comment: @Peminator: That is because it is the string (`__toString()`) value of that `<td>`-element representing SimpleXMLElement. It is plain text - not XML. Try `$tr->td[$i]->asXML()` instead and you'll see that it is with the surrounding `<td>...</td>` tags.

Comment: An IMSoP is right in my eyes, this is why I asked for more infos. I would have linked the exact same duplicate then.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps:

```
$titl[$i] = $tr->td[$i]->a[0]->children()->asXML();
```

Comment: ooooh thought u saved my day, but after trying it returns,based on the example above only the `<b>text</b>` instead `link<b>text</b>` - the non-bold text is missing...

Comment: oops, just noticed that

Comment: On SimpleXMLElement objects representing zero or more elements (like the return value of `children()`), the method normally only works for the first element (like the method named `asXML()`). SimpleXML has only limited support (if one would say so at all) for textnodes.