# PHP simplexml_load_string trims out any HTML in between two of the XML tags...how to keep?

Tags: php, html, simplexml

Below it he XML and the the XML parsed object..
The code used is

```php
$XML = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $XML); 
echo('\n\n'.$XML);
$xmldoc = simplexml_load_string($XML);
print_r($xmldoc);
$jsondoc = json_encode($xmldoc);
$phpobjectsdoc = json_decode($json, true);
```

```xml
<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">
<responseDate>2023-01-06T02:06:06Z</responseDate>
<request identifier="journals:aajses19230810-01" metadataPrefix="oai_dc" verb="GetRecord"> https://x.x.edu/journals/cgi-bin/bcjournals-oaiserver</request>
<GetRecord>
<record>
<header>
<identifier>bcjournals:aajses19230810-01</identifier>
<datestamp>2020-12-03</datestamp>
<setSpec>bcjournals:aajses-documents</setSpec>
</header>
<metadata>
<oai_dcdc xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
<dctitle>Bulletin of the American Association of Jesuit Scientists, Eastern Section</dctitle>
<dcdate>1923-08-10</dcdate>
<dcdescription>
Bulletin of the American Association of Jesuit Scientists, Eastern Section, 10 August 1923
<a href="https://xxx.xxx.edu/iiif/issue/aajses19230810-01/manifest.json?manifest=https%3a%2f%2fxxx.xxx.edu%2fiiif%2fissue%2faajses19230810-01%2fmanifest.json" target="_blank">
<img style="width: 20px;" alt="IIIF Collection Link" src="/custom/bournals/web/images/iiif-logo.png"/>
</a>
(22 pages, 19 articles)
</dcdescription>
<dclanguage>en</dclanguage>
</oai_dcdc>
</metadata>
</record>
</GetRecord>
</OAI-PMH>
```

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [responseDate] => 2023-01-06T02:06:06Z
    [request] =>  https://.ddd.edu/bcjournals/cg-bin/brnals-oaiserver
    [GetRecord] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [record] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [identifier] => bcrnals:aajses19230810-01
                            [datestamp] => 2020-12-03
                            [setSpec] => bnals:aajses-documents
                        )

                    [metadata] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [oai_dcdc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [dctitle] => Bulletin of the American Association of Jesuit Scientists, Eastern Section
                                    [dcdate] => 1923-08-10
                                    [dcdescription] => 
Bulletin of the American Association of Jesuit Scientists, Eastern Section, 10 August 1923

(22 pages, 19 articles)

                                    [dclanguage] => en
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not your fault, but you have managed to pick up on other people's terrible habits, and ended up digging yourself into an entirely unnecessary hole.

The first thing to understand is that **SimpleXML is an API, not a way to create plain PHP objects** - the structure of an XML document is (or can be) much more complex than a PHP object can easily represent, so SimpleXML provides ways to *access* the data, but doesn't put it all in obvious places.

So the first mistake that everyone makes is expecting this to work:

```
$xmldoc = simplexml_load_string($XML);
print_r($xmldoc);
```

The first line creates a [SimpleXMLElement object](https://php.net/SimpleXMLElement), and the second tries to display it - but unfortunately `print_r` doesn't know how to show all the data that's available, so **some of the object is invisible**. This confuses people into doing lots of unnecessary and counter-productive things, because they think the invisible things are *missing*.

The only real way to show what's inside the object, is to [turn it back into XML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php), at which point you'll see that everything is in fact still there:

```
$xmldoc = simplexml_load_string($XML);
echo $xmldoc->asXML();
```

---

Once you realise this, you'll realise that this line was unnecessary:

```
$XML = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $XML);
```

This is a *terrible* attempt at handling element and attribute names with colons in, which actually represent "XML Namespaces" - a relatively complex but useful way to combine different formats into one without names colliding (my `<link>` and your `<link>` can sit next to each other, and we can tell the difference). To handle them properly, see [Reference - How do I handle Namespaces (Tags and Attributes with a Colon in their Name) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894426/157957)

---

Obviously, most of the time you don't just want to see the XML again, you want to get data out of it. Because `print_r` isn't telling them how to do that, people use another *terrible* trick to get a different kind of object:

```
$jsondoc = json_encode($xmldoc);
$phpobjectsdoc = json_decode($json, true);
```

Do not do this. Once you've done this, that data that was invisible in `print_r` *really has gone for good*.

Instead, read [the examples in the manual of how to traverse a basic XML document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

---

So, back to your example. I've taken a guess at where the colons were before you removed them. Then I pasted it into a programmer's editor (in my case, PhpStorm) to automatically indent it for easier reading:

```xml
<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">
    <responseDate>2023-01-06T02:06:06Z</responseDate>
    <request identifier="journals:aajses19230810-01" metadataPrefix="oai_dc" verb="GetRecord"> https://x.x.edu/journals/cgi-bin/bcjournals-oaiserver</request>
    <GetRecord>
        <record>
            <header>
                <identifier>bcjournals:aajses19230810-01</identifier>
                <datestamp>2020-12-03</datestamp>
                <setSpec>bcjournals:aajses-documents</setSpec>
            </header>
            <metadata>
                <oai_dc:dc xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
                    <dc:title>Bulletin of the American Association of Jesuit Scientists, Eastern Section</dc:title>
                    <dc:date>1923-08-10</dc:date>
                    <dc:description>
                        Bulletin of the American Association of Jesuit Scientists, Eastern Section, 10 August 1923
                        <a href="https://xxx.xxx.edu/iiif/issue/aajses19230810-01/manifest.json?manifest=https%3a%2f%2fxxx.xxx.edu%2fiiif%2fissue%2faajses19230810-01%2fmanifest.json" target="_blank">
                            <img style="width: 20px;" alt="IIIF Collection Link" src="/custom/bournals/web/images/iiif-logo.png"/>
                        </a>
                        (22 pages, 19 articles)
                    </dc:description>
                    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
                </oai_dc:dc>
            </metadata>
        </record>
    </GetRecord>
</OAI-PMH>
```

Now, to get to the `dc:description` element, we need to walk through step by step:

```
// 1. Our initial object represents the root element, `<OAI=PMH>`
$xmldoc = simplexml_load_string($XML);

// 2. Unprefixed children are in namespace `http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/` namespace
//    because of the xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/"
$children = $xmldoc->children('http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/');

// 3. We want the element <GetRecord>
$GetRecord = $children->GetRecord;

// 4. Inside that, we want <record>, then <metadata>
$record = $GetRecord->record;
$metadata = $record->metadata;

// Or all in one statement:
$metadata = $xmldoc->children('http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/')
    ->GetRecord->record->metadata;

// 5. Now we have <oai_dc:dc> - a new namespace
// xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" so:
$dc = $metadata->children('http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/')->dc;

// 6. Another new namespace, for dc:description
// xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
$description = $dc->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/')->description;

// 7. At this point, see what we've got:
echo $description->asXML();
```

Giving

```xml
<dc:description>
Bulletin of the American Association of Jesuit Scientists, Eastern Section, 10 August 1923
<a href="https://xxx.xxx.edu/iiif/issue/aajses19230810-01/manifest.json?manifest=https%3a%2f%2fxxx.xxx.edu%2fiiif%2fissue%2faajses19230810-01%2fmanifest.json" target="_blank">
<img style="width: 20px;" alt="IIIF Collection Link" src="/custom/bournals/web/images/iiif-logo.png"/>
</a>
(22 pages, 19 articles)
</dc:description>
```

The description, with all its content in place!

---

There's one remaining problem: we don't really want the `<dc:description>` and `</dc:description>`, just the text in between. If the element only contained text, we could write `echo (string)$description;`. But if we do that here, the HTML disappears again - that's because whoever produced this data messed up a bit, and included the HTML without escaping it, so SimpleXML thinks the `<a>` and `<img>` elements are part of the XML structure, not the content.

Getting the "inner XML" is one thing that SimpleXML doesn't have a neat method for, but [there are tricks for doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937056/php-simplexml-get-innerxml):

```
$content= '';
foreach (dom_import_simplexml($description)->childNodes as $child)
{
    $content .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );
}
echo $content;
```

Giving

```html
Bulletin of the American Association of Jesuit Scientists, Eastern Section, 10 August 1923
<a href="https://xxx.xxx.edu/iiif/issue/aajses19230810-01/manifest.json?manifest=https%3a%2f%2fxxx.xxx.edu%2fiiif%2fissue%2faajses19230810-01%2fmanifest.json" target="_blank">
<img style="width: 20px;" alt="IIIF Collection Link" src="/custom/bournals/web/images/iiif-logo.png"/>
</a>
(22 pages, 19 articles)
```

Perfect!

---

If that looks long-winded, that's just because I stopped to explain along the way; here's a tidied up version:

```
$xmldoc = simplexml_load_string($XML);

$description = $xmldoc
    ->children('http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/')
        ->GetRecord->record->metadata
    ->children('http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/')
        ->dc
    ->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/')
        ->description;

$content= '';
foreach (dom_import_simplexml($description)->childNodes as $child)
{
    $content .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );
}
```