# Content in xml parse script show as array instead html

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

When I parse xml one object is shown as array because it has

tags inside. How to use it as html content instead?

Here is xml data:

```
<product>
  <id>10001</id>
  <sku>SKU0001</sku>
  <name>Product name</name>
  <stock>SKU0001</stock>
  <description><p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p><p>Paragraph 3</p></description>
</product>
```

Here is part of my code:

```
$url = "https://url.com/products.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");
$sku = $xml->product->product_id;
$name = $xml->product->identifier;
$description = $xml->product->description;
$stock = $xml->product->stock;              
print_r($description);
```

`print_r($description)` returns me this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [p] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paragraph 1
            [1] => Paragraph 2
            [2] => Paragraph 3
        )

)
```

I would like to see `$desription` as html: `<p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p><p>Paragraph 3</p>`.

Comment: Something like `foreach($xml->product->description as $description) echo '<p>' . $description . '</p>'; }` should do it

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937056/php-simplexml-get-innerxml

Comment: Or you can use xpath: `echo $xml->xpath('//description')[0]->asXML();`

Comment: I suspect that those `<p></p>` tags were not meant to be part of the XML structure. Is this XML data something you generate (thus you can fix)?